# Conky: Use command output for formatting

Tags: gnome, conky

I'm having an issue with dynamic positioning of images. Basically I made a Conky theme that will move depending on the circumstances. At the bottom of this theme is a process table. I have images inserted as the vertical lines of this table, but I need them to move automatically.

I have a script that will return either `560`, `610`, or `660` depending on the circumstance. These numbers are `y` coordinates for the images. I can display the output of the script in Conky via the command:
`${exec bash /etc/conky/network.sh}`. How can I use this as an integer to position my images? I've tried: `${image /etc/conky/Line.png -p 120, ${exec bash /etc/conky/network.sh} -s 1x180}` to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
execp   command  differs from $exec in that it parses the output of the command, so you can insert things like ${color red}hi!${color} in your script and have it correctly parsed by Conky. Caveats: Conky parses and evaluates the output of $execp every time Conky loops, and then destroys all the objects. If you try to use anything like $execi within an $execp statement, it will functionally run at the same interval that the $execp statement runs, as it is created and destroyed at every interval.
```

you can have /etc/conky/network.sh output: `${image /etc/conky/Line.png -p 120,560 -s 1x180}`
or output the other 2 if you can determine the circumstances in the script.

this`${execp bash /etc/conky/network.sh}`

will replace `${image /etc/conky/Line.png -p 120, ${exec bash /etc/conky/network.sh} -s 1x180}`

in your script